# Motivic measure

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, algebraic-geometry

Somebody  can give me some good references for start to read Motivic-measure, Now I`m studing the Grothendieck Ring, and is necesary undertand something of motivic theory for my case, so I need a good and quick reference for motivic measure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introductory article [*What is motivic measure?*](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-02/S0273-0979-05-01053-0/) by Tom Hales is a good start.

The article of Cluckers and Loeser, [*Constructible motivic functions and motivic integration*](https://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0031940/prints/cons_fin.pdf) seems to be a standard introductory reference, though there are different approaches.